# LINQ to SQL. Visualizer Debugger not showing SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, debugging, visual-studio-2010

In [this](http://www.asp.net/linq/videos/how-do-i-linq-to-sql-querying-the-database) example, this screen shot of the video shows that if you click on the following magnifying class tooltip, it will bring up a debugger that shows you the SQL tghat the LINQ statment has been converted into:

[image]

However, when I download the sample VB code and run it and try to do the same thing in VS2010 Ultimate, I see the following. Notice that the magnifying lense visualizer icon is not available.

What am I missing? Do I need to install a separate debugger? My dataset visualizer works fine...

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# retrieve where clause on linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405260/c-retrieve-where-clause-on-linq)

Comment: Not even close. I don't just want ANY way to see the SQL. I want to know why the visualizer isn't working and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the visualizer is not working for you, but in case you don't find a solution another (less convenient) way to view the SQL is to assign a `TextWriter` (for example `Console.Out`) to [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the queries being executed through SQL server profiler.